# OrientDB schema migration tool for Java

Tags: java, orientdb, database-migration

Is there a tool for managing changes of **OrientDB** schemas?

I am familiar with *[Flyway](https://github.com/flyway/flyway)*, but it has no support for OrientDB, so it will be great if there is something similar you could recommend.

My requirements are below:

- Written in Java
- Can use native OrientDB API to execute queries (not only JDBC)
- Can use Java based migrations (not only queries)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

See this related [feature request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/947) already added to the [Flyway 5.2.0 milestone](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/milestone/18), but no ETA announced.

We're currently investigating contributing to this, as we'll need that exact feature.